# Expo: how to get RAM used?

Tags: react-native, performance, expo, ram

How to get RAM used in Expo (React-Native)? Even a console print out would be great.

This seems to give a dump of memory

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo
```

But its very non-user friendly.

Performance monitor on the device does not show RAM for some reason:

[image]

Expo device api (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/device/) does not seem to provide current memory usage. And it sounds like we would need to eject out of expo to be able to use 'react-native-device-info'.